# Apache looking for wrong directory in git-http-backend configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, http, git

I wouldn't be posting here unless I've run out of options. *Be forewarned, I could be making a very simple rookie mistake.*

I'm trying to set up the git-http-backend on Ubuntu Server 12.04. I've gone through all the tutorials and configurations I've found on Kernel.org, the various Ubuntu sites, git-scm, Serverfault, etc. But no matter what I do, my Apache error log shows that it is looking for my git repos in /var/www when my virtual host directive is set to /home/git/repos.

I've been trying to clone the repo on my Ubuntu server box to my Windows 8 machine via http. In the Windows GUI I input http://git@server.home.lan/git/project3.git into the clone dialog but the client (and git bash) return the following error.

> fatal:
>   http://git@server.home.lan/git/project3.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>   not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

at the same time, the Apache error log delivers the following:

> [Sun Feb 03 20:12:08 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.135] File does
>   not exist: /var/www/git

My Apache virtualhost for the Git http backend is configured as follows. I have tried many, many variations of this but I have always gotten the same error.

This configuration is located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/git

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git/repos
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/bin/git-http-backend/

ServerName server.home.lan

DocumentRoot "/home/git/repos"

<Directory "/home/git/repos">
Options None
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Git"
Require group committers
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you have the right permissions on the folders git should enter?

Comment: I believe so. I added the git user to the www-data group and set the folder's owner to www-data:www-data.

Comment: do a grep through your apache conf to find out if /var/www/git is referenced anywhere. Alternatively, do you have another virtual host entry which functions as the default which is getting hit instead?